# Змерзнути і замерзнути - абсолютні синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

Відповідно до [Словника синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B20)

> МЕ́РЗНУТИ [МЕ́РЗТИ] (твердіти від морозу, перетворюватися на лід),
> ЗАМЕРЗА́ТИ, ЗМЕРЗА́ТИ, МОРО́ЗИТИСЯ розм.; ПРОМЕРЗА́ТИ,
> ПРОМОРО́ЖУВАТИСЯ розм. (наскрізь або частково); ЛЕДЕНІ́ТИ
> (перетворюватися на лід або вкриватися кригою). - Док.: ***зме́рзнути***
> [зме́рзти], ***заме́рзнути*** [заме́рзти], проме́рзнути [проме́рзти],
> проморо́зитися, заледені́ти.

Змерзнути і замерзти - синоніми.
Але в СУМ-20 - [змерзнути](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36877&page=1159) та [замерзнути](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=30584&page=1000) мають дещо різне значення .

Ци можемо вживати ці слова як повні синоніми?Чи варто розмежовувати вживання слів?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вирішив пошукати ще декілька джерел, де йшлося про це питання.

[Експрес-уроки української мови](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol2tn6WYozw) з Олександром Авраменком:

> Хоч слова "змерзнути" і "замерзнути" походять від одного кореня, проте
>   лише через одну літеру "а" вони відрізняються. "**Замерзнути**" означає
>   "стати твердим від холоду", "вкритися шаром льоду" або "загинути від
>   холоду". "**Змерзати**" - "відчувати холод", "страждати від холоду".
>   Приклади:
>
> Я вискочив на вулицю, а **земля замерзла**.
>
> Так, треба одягнутися тепліше, бо вже **трохи змерз**.

Сайт "[Мова ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zmerznutu-j-zamerznutu)" також розрізняє ці слова і цитує мовознавця Олександра Пономарева:

> Обидва ці слова походять від одного кореня, проте їх не можна вживати
>   одне замість одного. **Замерзнути** означає «стати твердим від холоду,
>   перетворитися на кригу; згинути від холоду»: «Замерзло поле скрізь»
>   (Є. Гребінка); «Там, де верби, тини і тополі, по ночах замерзає вода»
>   (В. Сосюра); «Галки на деревах замерзали і, як шматки льоду, падали
>   додолу» (Панас Мирний). А **змерзнути** — це відчути холод: «Змерзла ж
>   то так, що зуб з зубом не зведе, так і труситься» (Г.
>   Квітка-Основ’яненко); «Зима не здавалась. Вівдя задмухала на світло. —
>   Дивіться, як парує! Хіба ви не змерзли?» (М. Хвильовий).

Про це саме йдеться на сайті "[Онлайн Коректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%96-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8/)":

> Перевірте вживання:
>
> **змерзнути, змерзати** — відчути холод;
>
> і **замерзнути, замерзати** — стати твердим від холоду, перетворитися на
>   кригу; згинути від холоду.

Приклади:

> **Змерзла** ж Маруся то так, що зуб з зубом не зведе, так і труситься (Григорій Квітка-Основ’яненко).
>
> Його відерце перше пробиває лід у криниці, що уночі **замерзає**
>   (Марко Вовчок).

Answer (score 3):

Згідно з трактовкою, яку дає «Словник української мови» в 20 томах, це виглядає так…

І *змерзнути* (*змерзати*), і *замерзнути* (*замерзати*) мають усі три такі значення: (а) відчувати холод чи страждати від нього; (б) твердіти від холоду; (в) помирати від холоду.

Але: слово *замерзнути* (*замерзати*), здається, є різкішим, позначає сильніший ступінь. Я роблю такий висновок з того, що:

1. Значення, яке я інтерпретую для себе як «(а) відчувати холод чи страждати від нього», в *змерзнути* (*змерзати*) дослівно сформульоване так — «відчувати холод, страждати від холоду; мерзнути (у 2 знач.)», а в *замерзнути* (*замерзати*) так — «**дуже** мерзнути».
2. Значення, яке я інтерпретую для себе як «(в) помирати від холоду», у *змерзнути* (*змерзати*) має позначку «перев[ажно] док[онане], розм[овне]» й посилається в інтерпретації на слово *замерзнути* (*замерзати*), в той час як у *замерзнути* (*замерзати*) — не має позначок (і зворотних відсилок). Тобто складається враження, що це значення для *замерзнути* (*замерзати*) є повноцінним, а для *змерзнути* (*змерзати*) має звужений ужиток.
3. У *змерзнути* (*змерзати*) першим у переліку йде значення, яке я інтерпретую для себе як «(а) відчувати холод чи страждати від нього», а в *замерзнути* (*замерзати*) першим іде значення, яке я інтерпретую для себе як «(б) твердіти від холоду».

Але мої висноски можуть бути помилковими, бо я базую їх суто на одному джерелі, причому приділяючи велику увагу дрібницям, про які я невпевнений, що його автори вважали їх суттєвими.